# How to implement concepts in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, c++-concepts

Where do I get to see the concepts getting implemented strictly using C++11 language and library features? 
I will prefer a simple library to start using it right away.

Comment: Well, C++11 static checks implement a huge part of what concepts were to have. Do you have any specific functionality in mind?

Comment: Didn't concepts get cut from the C++-11 standard?

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Hence this question, I think.

Comment: I was referring to the famous paper "A Concept Design for the STL"  by Dr. Bjarne Stroustrup, which inspired me to dive into Origin C++ Libraries, which is an implementation using C++11. I ended up collating the ideas with our experiments to put these into work in my book : "Foundation of Algorithms in C++11, Volume 1 : Using And Extending C++11, Boost And Beyond". But to go further, we need a complete set-up for C++11 concepts and Origin libraries are still very incomplete and experimental in nature.Can someone point to a library, which is put to practice?.Any pointer will be very helpful.

Comment: I assume you didn't mean "C++ Concepts & Axioms" which (as originally proposed) cannot be fully implemented as a library feature. What exactly are you looking for, I still don't understand...

Comment: @Paul: A Concept Design of STL proposes:`template<BidirectionalIterator I, BidirectionalIterator Out>
requires IndirectlyCopyable<I, Out>
Out copy_backward(I first, I last, Out result);`

Comment: @Paul: A Concept Design of STL proposes:`template<BidirectionalIterator I, BidirectionalIterator Out>
requires IndirectlyCopyable<I, Out>
Out copy_backward(I first, I last, Out result);` which cannot be implemented using just library features. So I reduced it to : `template<typename I, typename I>
requires<IndirectlyCopyable<I, Out>() && Bidirectional_Iterator<I>()>
Out copy_backward(I first, I last, Out result);`. This I was able to get it easily using sfinae feature : enable_if. But I was looking for something like this in a form of a full blown C++11 library.

Comment: Using template alias and sfinae, simulation of requires may look like : `#include <type_traits>

template <bool Condition, typename T = void>
using requires = typename std::enable_if<Condition, T>::type;`

Comment: And the Conditions being passed to requires can be simulated using constexpr like: `template <typename I, typename Out> constexpr bool IndirectlyCopyable() { ...}` and `template <typename I> constexpr bool Bidirectional_Iterato() { ...}`

Comment: So, all I am looking for a C++11 library, which fully implement C++11 Algorithms using Concepts as part of algorithm's interface as in : `template<typename I, typename I> requires<IndirectlyCopyable<I, Out>() && Bidirectional_Iterator<I>()> Out copy_backward(I first, I last, Out result)` or `template<typename I, typename I> auto copy_backward(I first, I last, Out result) -> requires<IndirectlyCopyable<I, Out>() && Bidirectional_Iterator<I>(), Out>` or something similar. Origin C++ library has similar components in place, but it is still a work in progress.

Comment: I assume you've looked into Boost.Concept and it's usage across other boost libraries, didn't you?

Comment: You can define concept predicates called traits using the [Tick](https://github.com/pfultz2/Tick) library. Its fairly similar to the concepts-lite proposal.